# Как удалить повторения между двумя файлами?

Tags: c#

Есть 2 файла:

```
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string[] file2 = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
```

каждый файл имеет вид:

```
654842
13216596
18784
...
```

Нужно произвести сравнение ВТОРОГО файла по отношению к первому - если во втором файле есть такое число, которого нет в первом, то оно записывается в новый третий файл, если такое число есть в первом файле, то берётся для проверки новое число. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Сделать это можно ровно так, как вы описали: прочитать оба файла, проверять наличие в первом числа из второго, если нет - оно записывается в новый третий файл.

Comment: А строки из файлов разделены /n ? То есть имеют точно такой же вид как Вы и указали ?

Comment: @kxxko да, вот так string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines(path).Split('\n');;

Comment: И с каких пор у массива есть Split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для сравнения лучше всего использовать `HashSet`. В этом случае поиск по коллекции происходит за O(1).

```
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(path2);    

var hash = new HashSet<string>(file1);
var list = new List<string>();

foreach(var str in file2)
    if (!hash.Contains(str))
        list.Add(str);

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\result.txt", list);
```

Этот пример будет работать, если данные из первого файла можно целиком уместить в память.

Для любителей Linq цикл `foreach` можно заменить так:

```
var list = file2.Where(x => !hash.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Очень симпатичный пример !

Comment: Прям после этого полез в исходники FCL, что бы посмотреть как работает `Enumerable.Except`, там тоже используется HashSet.. Хороший пример.

Comment: Linq по моему вообще няшка =) С ним намного все проще !

Comment: Ответ впринципе правильный, но условие в if неверное, автор вопроса просил записывать в третий файл число которого НЕТ в первом, а в ответе наоборот, записывается число которое ЕСТЬ в первом файле

Comment: @IvanParfentev точно! Исправил.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант можно воспользоватся методом `System.Linq.Enumerable.Except<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)`

```
string[] file1 = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
string[] file2 = File.ReadAllLines("2.txt");

var diff = file1.Except(file2);

foreach (var item in diff)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите каждую цифру из строки и сравните ее так:

```
 foreach(var value1 in textFile1)
    {
        foreach(var value2 in textfile2)
        {
            if(value2 != value1) { // File.Create(3ий_файл); }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Или вопрос состоит в том, как достать одну считать каждую строку из файла ?
То тогда запишите каждую строку из файла в `массив`:

```
string[] Mass = File.ReadAllLines(@"путь к файлу", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

На второй файл точно такой же массив создайте.
И уже каждый элемент этого массива сравнивайте с элементом второго массива.

Comment: Кстати, ваш ответ с циклами не решает задачу.

Comment: @pavelip а он и не должен ее решить, а должен показать как можно решить. Темболее уже есть хороший ответ.